# ExQueueWorkItem, FltQueueGenericWorkItem, or FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem?

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel, driver, minifilter

As we know, in Windows NT kernel, there are three ways to post a work item to execute in a system thread environment at PASSIVE_LEVEL.

i.e. `ExQueueWorkItem`, `FltQueueGenericWorkItem`, and `FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem`.

However, I just wonder their differences and their respective application scenarios.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of each API:

`ExQueueWorkItem` : Can be used by drivers where there isn't any framework apis provided for such work. The documentation suggests to use `IoQueueWorkItem` instead.

`FltQueueGenericWorkItem`: For minifilter drivers, shall use this to do any non-IO related work. Like some periodic cleanup etc.

`FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem`: For minifilter drivers for work related to IO operation. I.e. if you are filtering an IO, you can defer some work related to that IO using this function.